When is it possible to omit "generic types" in TypeScript?
I noticed that, often, the TypeScript compiler doesn't complain if I don't pass a parametrised type:
function someFunction<T>(): T {
  // Do something
}

const x = someFunction<string>();

// I'd personally expect this line to ALWAYS raise a compiler error
// but this is not the case
const y = someFunction();

In some cases it does raise an error, other times it doesn't, and I don't see a pattern behind this behaviour.
I guess that, in some cases, the structure of the function itself suggests the compiler what the type T is, and in those cases it's probably correct that it doesn't get flagged.
But I did a couple of experiments, and there are confusing results.

Experiment 1
function cannotBeInferred<T>(): T {
  return 0 as T;
}

const a1 = cannotBeInferred();
const a2 = cannotBeInferred<string>();


Variable a1 is unknown: I'd definitely expect the compiler to raise an error
Variable a2 is string, as expected


Experiment 2
function canBeInferredNativeType<T>(par: T): T {
  return par;
}

const b1 = canBeInferredNativeType('test');
const b2 = canBeInferredNativeType<string>('test');


Variable b1 is of type "test" - I'd expect the compiler to raise an error here
Variable b2 is string as expected


Experiment 3
function canBeInferredInterface<T>(param: { something: T }): T {
  return param.something;
}

interface Something { something: string };
const param: Something = { something: 'blabla' };

const c1 = canBeInferredInterface({ something: 'test' });
const c2 = canBeInferredInterface(param);
const c3 = canBeInferredInterface<number>({ something: 123 });


Variable c1 is string; I'd expect the compiler to raise an error here, because how does it know that the interface I am passing is { something: string } and not { something: 'test' }?
Variable c2 is string; in my view it's correct that the compiler didn't raise an error, because the parameter I am passing is explicitly typed; but I do find this example a bit convoluted, I'd still prefer the compiler to fail here
Variable c3 is correctly number



What I would like is a uniform behaviour. Either raise an error every single time that I don't provide the parameter; or otherwise be crystal clear that, when errors are not raised, it means that the type is obvious from the context.
How can I achieve this? Is there a compiler option for this?

Given your question and example the answer is: every time, typescript will just infer the best matching type and if it can't you get an unknown. Why should it raise an error instead? You will get an error once you start using the resulting variable if you assume it to be a specific type vs. the unknown that it is. Can you provide an example where it raises an error that you did not expect or that is inconsistent the behaviour observed here?

@luk2302 hmm you are right, things probably work well already; probably this is just my OCD complaining about not seeing the type parameters consistently, and it should be handled with a lint rule, rather than at compiler level

It is possible to omit generic type parameters in Typescript as soon as:

They're optional, ie when a defautl value has been specified
type Type<Optional = string> = .....
=> you can use Type without specifying the generic parameter but then it will be string
They are inferable and not partially specified

type Func<Input, Return> = (input: Input) => Return;

const hoist = <Input, Return>(func: Func<Input, Return>, input: Input) => {

 return func(input);
}

const hoistReturnNumber = <Input, Return = number>(func: Func<Input, Return>, input: Input) => {

 return hoist<Input, Return>(func, input);
}

// none specified, fully inferable => OK
hoist((a: string) => parseInt(a), '12')

// first specified, second optional => OK
hoistReturnNumber<string>((a: string) => parseInt(a), '12')

// fully inferable but first specified while second mandatory => ERROR
hoist<string>((a: string) => parseInt(a), '12')

// fully specified
hoist<string, number>((a: string) => parseInt(a), '12')


Now even if it triggers OCD, having infered generic parameters allows for deep inference and really generic code that will not need painfull refactoring when the manipulated types change.
